# Unable to connect to the NetBeans 8.0.1

Tags: performance, netbeans, netbeans-8

When i try to update plugin i am getting this error :-
Unable to connect to the NetBeans Distribution because of Address family not supported by protocol family: connect

Comment: are you using proxy ?

Comment: no @Ravi i am not using proxy